# Oracle multi-user application staging tables - in APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, multi-user

I'm developing an application which takes some raw input data and transforms it to calculate a final result in a series of steps. At each of these steps, there are possible user inputs (e.g., weights, selecting relevant rows, etc.). I've got the basic analysis set up, but my goal is to deploy this in a multi-user environment. What I don't want to have happen is for one user to set their inputs, have another user change some inputs, and both get unexpected results.

When a user enters an application, I'd like them to get a copy of all of the main database tables as they stand when beginning a session, then be able to change all of the inputs (possibly even adding raw data), running an analysis and generating output that is kept separate from all other users' output. This output might be exported to Excel, or it could be pulled out at a later date. Then, if the user wants to make the changes they made to the actual database tables (which all other users will see), they can commit some or all of their changes.

I'm an Oracle and APEX newbie and have been reading all the documentation and books I can lay my hands on, but need help identifying good approaches to this problem, or at least relevant reading.

Comment: Why not add a `USERID` column to your staging tables, populate and filter with the apex function `V('USER')`.

Comment: This is a good idea - I still have to figure out what to do about the outputs, but I hadn't thought of this. Thanks!

Comment: Would you really want to do this? Copy over the data from the "source table"? What if this table is very large? If that table has 100000 rows and you have 10 users you suddenly end up with 10 times as much data. Keep performance in mind. If you're really a newbie to both oracle and apex, I'd advise to get to grips with it first - and mainly apex, and try to see how it works and what the limitations are. Apex is a great tool and allows for a lot, but you will simply struggle if you do not attune your solution to the product you work with.

Comment: Tom, do you have any better ideas? I've since moved forward with Vincent's idea. The thing is that it's not only possible, but likely that users will make changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use APEX Collections.

Look http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_collection.htm

UPD:

You must look for apex collections. First of all: when user login in, create one empty apex collection for each table you want change. Collection name must named like a corresponding table. Then you may create views for each collection looking like (let the table name is "tmp_tab"):

```
create or replace view tmp_v as
select
  t.c001 as id
, t.c002 as column1
, t.c003 as column2
 from apex_collections t
 where collection_name = 'tmp_tab';
```

Then in each report for table tmp_tab join this table with his view on corresponding collection. Code of report will look like this:

```
select
  t.id
, nvl(v.column1, t.column1) column1
, nvl(v.column2, t.column2) column2
 from tmp_tab t
 left join tmp_v v on v.id = t.id
```

Then, when user edit data, save this data not in table, save it in collection. After all changes made, if user wants save data for all users, move data into the tables from corresponding collections. This way will be most right, and you don't change your data model.

Comment: One mistake: there will be not left join. There must be full outer join to include new rows that user just added.